# Bound mismatch: The generic method add(T) of type

Tags: java, mysql, database, api

Please help me to save the different information in different database.

My problem is the `dataService.add();`. The error message is

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `add(T)` of type `IfDataOpe` is not applicable for the arguments (`List<BetRecordAgBR>`). The inferred type `List<BetRecordAgBR>` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Entity>`

```
@Test
public void BetHistoryAGIN() throws Exception {

    IfDataOpe dataService = new DataService();
    PlatformType type = PlatformType.AG;
    AGService service = new AGService();
    Parameter para = new Parameter();
    Parameter para1 = new Parameter();
    para.setKey("username");
    para.setValue("Value1");
    para1.setKey(password);
    para1.setValue("Value2");
    Parameter[] paras = new Parameter[2];
    paras[0] = para;
    paras[1] = para1;
    List<BetRecordAgBR> recordBr = service.getBetHistory(type,
            BetRecordAgBR.class, paras);

    dataService.setEntityManager(em);
    EntityTransaction tran = em.getTransaction();
    tran.begin();
    dataService.add(recordBr);
    tran.commit();

    List<BetRecordAgEBR> recordEbr = service.getBetHistory(type,
            BetRecordAgEBR.class, paras);

    List<BetRecordAgGR> recordGr = service.getBetHistory(type,
            BetRecordAgGR.class, paras);

    List<BetRecordAgTR> recordTr = service.getBetHistory(type,
            BetRecordAgTR.class, paras);

}
```

}

Comment: The error states that you cannot pass `recordBr` to `dataService.add();` method. The parameter should be a subclass of `Entity`.

Comment: thanks for the response what should i need to do to pass the recordBr to dataService.add();?